# Do multiple callback reduce nodejs performance?

Tags: node.js, express, callback, promise, rxjs

I am developing an express app with mysql. My node version is 6.11.2.

My router file is

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const project = require("../../modules/project/");

// individual project routes
router.get("/", project.getAllProject);
```

Now my getAllProject function code as follows.

```
  /* Get all project  */
  getAllProject(req, res, next) {
    buildQuery(req) /* Build query based on logged in user */
      .then(query => runDbQuery(req, query)) /* execute query */
      .then(results => formatResult(results)) /* Build response for front end */
      .then(output => res.send(output)) /* return results */
      .catch(err =>
        next(err, req, res, next)
      ); /* catch error and pass it error middle ware */
  }
```

buildQuery, runDbQuery, fromatResult return promise.

On my code review client commented as below

> In your method here called “getAllProjects” there
>   are 3 callback checks needed to be made and completed before the data is delivered and a total of 4 callbacks in all.  This is too many. This is slow because these
>   callbacks need to complete before the data can be sent to the client which is taking up server processing power

He also asked me to do everything in one callback and return data to client. Do promise and callback approach reduce performance. He also suggest to use RXJS Observable  in express.

Comment: You have to specify more details like what these function do @shameersn

Comment: @ Sumeet buildQuery returns sql query string, runDbQuery execute mysql query returned by buildQuery, formatResult create a json from mysql results. These functions resolve or reject based on some conditions like, if there is a mysql execution error then it will reject with error, else resolve with results. I am using msql package for executing mysql query

Comment: @Sumeet the question is about the single vs multiple `.then()` ways, not about the work they do

Comment: How much call back or promise is included in the code is not the vital factor for performance in my own opinion. If functions needs to be split up for readability and maintainability it is well worth it. Rxjs doesn't solve such problem, you will still make a choice between multiple flatmap or one big function

Comment: @FanCheung Thanks

Comment: @shameersn did you see the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, each function invocation costs some resources (like context/closure construction). So, yeah, having three `.then()` is by definition *slower* than a single `.then()` even if same work is done in both case inside those then-s.

It is really hard to tell *how much* the multi-then case is slower compared to the single-then case without running a benchmark ...so, I created a [simple one](https://jsperf.com/test-promises) which you can try yourself.

On my old and really sloooooooooow laptop, the results of the benchmark look likes this:

[image: result]

Hope, this answers your question.

---

Now, performance is not the only criteria for code assessment. The other one is readability. In some cases your code will look *more readable* if you have multiple `.then()` calls, where each declares a specific data transformation step. Just a side note. **I *personally* prefer readability over performance**, because to me it's picking **higher chance of correctness over performance**. Your client may think differently.

---

As far as the `Observable` goes, you may or may not want to use them. It depends on the nature of your app. `Observable` rocks when it comes to event streams and manipulation. `Promises`, however, rock with ES6's `await/async` feature. So, no clear answer here, unless we know more about the context.

Comment: Thanks. Now i have to sacrifice readability for performance and client happiness

Comment: @shameersn do not get upset. It's kinda part of our job. And it's client's call anyway; plus the client is the one who pays...

Comment: Dear down voter, would you explain what's wrong with my answer?